# What can threads do that processes can't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like some input on this since it would help guide as to what I should focus on in my studies (if I should consider threads at all).

Are there examples of Rails application where threads are absolutely necessary and the multiple process model can't provide an adequate solution. One exception would be an application that has memory restrictions and would need to use threads instead of spawning multiple processes. But assuming that memory is not an issue, what are some additional cases where threads are the better bet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads are easier to write and debug. I'll start with simple non-threaded code, debug it, then wrap a chunk with `Thread.new` and `join` at the end and I'm done.

And, yes, study them. You'll learn useful techniques and gain knowledge that's going to be good to have in your "programming toolchest".

As far as what can threads do that processes can't? Threads can very easily share data and work from the same queue or queues. Doing that with separate processes requires a database or IPC or using a messaging queue, all which add a lot of complexity (though they can also increase capacity too.)

Comment: Most of the time I read about the complications and complexity of threads not their simplicity. So much so that many programmers seem to gladly take the extra effort of a separate inter-process messaging queues into account. Do you agree with this?

Comment: I think it depends on the complexity of the job. Threads aren't for heavy-weight tasks, at least not what we have now. We use a MQ at work to manage some jobs that used to take 24+hours to run, which we reduced to < 1hr with some Ruby and a small *nix host. Threads wouldn't have done it. But, again, writing nodes for MQ can be overkill too, so you have to consider the job and do what makes sense for that job.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Threads are more efficient to create / tear-down than processes.

[SideKiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) is more efficient than [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) largely because SideKiq workers are Threads, whereas Resque use forked workers (processes).

But the problem is that Ruby on MRI doesn't have native threads, so each Thread in Ruby is limited by the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). See this Igvita article for more information: http://www.igvita.com/2008/11/13/concurrency-is-a-myth-in-ruby/

On platforms with native threads such as JRuby you can have a multi-threaded Rails app (running in a servlet container) and it will likely out-perform the same app running under MRI. Its also possible that JRuby on the Hotspot JVM can do just-in-time performance optimizations as well.